# How to Encrypt and decrypt a Text in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

**I need store the secure information in AsyncStorage** ,

So please any one explain how Encrypt and decrypt a Text  in react native

Comment: you can check [react-native-rsa](https://github.com/z-hao-wang/react-native-rsa) library.

Comment: Thanks @milkersarac

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57382721/how-can-i-generate-hmac-in-react-native/67602394#67602394

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use crypto-js library https://github.com/brix/crypto-js. Works fine within React Native app.

```
npm install crypto-js --save
```

---

```
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");

var ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt('my message', 'secret key 123');
console.log("encrypted text", ciphertext.toString());

var bytes  = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ciphertext.toString(), 'secret key 123');
var plaintext = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
console.log("decrypted text", plaintext);
```

Comment: Thank You  @vinayr

Comment: Unfortunately, `crypto-js` doesn't support RSA, and there doesn't look like to be one in the future.

Comment: thank you, saved my day!

Comment: I'm getting malformed UTF-8 error everytime and none of the solutions suggested works

Comment: (As of Mar-2023!) If you are using this from React-Native, be aware that the latest version will throw an error, "**Native crypto module could not be used to get secure random number.**" To get around this you'll have to force a downgrade, as described in [this unresolved issue for crypto-js from 2020](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/issues/256).

Comment: use react-native-crypto-js, works for me!