# How can I generate HMAC in React-Native?

Tags: react-native, encryption, cryptojs

I need to create HmacSHA256 from a string with a private key...
I use react-native-crypto-js but I cant use it's HmacSHA256 method,
it keeps getting me "undefined function" error, here is my code:

```
const signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256('simple', '123456789');
    const signatureBase = signature.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
```

I followed it's document either but still getting same error,
if you know another solution or the correct way to use this package please help me.
thanks.

Comment: Hey, I want to check, if you find the resolution of above issue. let me know.

Answer (score 2):

I found a work around for **react native windows HmacSHA256** Algorithm. I have used 2 packages

**Step 1:**

```
  npm install --save  react-native-hash //install this
  import { JSHash, JSHmac, CONSTANTS } from "react-native-hash";

  JSHmac("message", "SecretKey", CONSTANTS.HmacAlgorithms.HmacSHA256)
  .then(hash => hmac_encoded_str=hash)
  .catch(e => console.log(e));

  OR
  let hmac_encoded_str= await JSHmac(canonical_string, "C6PqJwbyW4", 
  CONSTANTS.HmacAlgorithms.HmacSHA256)
```

**Step 2:**

```
  npm install react-native-crypto-js // install this as well
  
  import CryptoJS from "react-native-crypto-js"
  
  CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(hmac_encoded_str));
```

Comment: How are these steps related?

Answer (score 0):

Use crypto-js.

How to install [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47766755/using-crypto-js-in-react)

---

How to use:

```
import base64 from 'crypto-js/enc-base64';
import hmac from 'crypto-js/hmac-sha256';

const sig = hmac(str, key).toString(base64);
```